# Speed leveling in Killing Floor

Tags: killing-floor

In Killing Floor I want to speed level some perks in order to play the higher difficulties.

What is a good strategy for quickly leveling perks that gain experience through damage? The perks I'm talking about are Support Specialist, Berserker, Firebug, and Demolitions. Most of mine are at level 2 now, so I'd like to know what game length and difficulty is best for leveling now and as my class level goes up.

I also realize that the Support Specialist, Berserker, Firebug, and Demolitions all do damage in very different ways. Are there any any maps and mutations that best help level any of these classes in particular?

Comment: To everyone that comes across this question: Please don't power level in Killing Floor.  This is a game where skill matters more than perk level, and by power leveling you are depriving yourself of time and experience gaining actual skill at the game.  I've seen plenty of level 6's wipe embarrassingly on Normal, and there are people out there who can solo Hell on Earth with level 1 or 2 perks.  Just play the game.

Comment: People should learn, but soloing Hell on Earth at low levels is literally total hell to do, it feels like a waste of time because your damage is low. The fact that you can survive doesn't change the speed at which you complete it when you're level 5+. Also, most pub servers don't let me play harder difficulties because I'm not high enough level. I'm very tired of Normal and Hard games only, which I find too easy at this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is a good strategy for quickly leveling perks that gain experience through damage? The perks I'm talking about are Support Specialist, Berserker, Firebug, and Demolitions.

Don't play single-player please. It's not very fun, and you will not learn from other people. Most of these tips to follow, I've gained through watching other people play. The best advice I can give you is to find out what your perk specializes in and do that. Don't do things your perk is not great at :)

**Support Specialist**

- Weld doors if your team holes up
  somewhere.
- Aim for the head. Shotguns penetrate
  through several enemies much easier
  if you aim for the head instead of
  the chest.
- Crouch when you see crawlers
  (everyone hates those nasty little
  turds)
- Don't buy armor/grenades/pistol ammo
  for the first 4-5 waves in order to
  save up for an AA12. This is good
  advice for other classes too.

**Berserker**

- If your team holes up somewhere, you
  should be at the front, soaking in
  the damage. Everything should attack
  you first. You should get a decent
  medic (get a mic and use it, it makes
  life much easier)
- You can stun certain enemies,
  especially scrakes. This is important
  -- read up on kf-wiki.com how to do it.
- Learn to know when you're getting
  screwed. You move fast as a zerker so
  you can run away -- just be sure to
  run away before being really screwed
  :)

**Firebug**

- Religiously leave "big" things like
  scrakes and fleshpounds to other
  perks. Just run away :)
- Watch when your friendlies are
  getting screwed and unload your whole
  canister into them. Demolition
  players especially will love you if
  you help them out when they're
  screwed and overran by small things.
- Don't annoy your team with flames --
  it really makes it hard to aim and it
  blurs everyone's vision. Stand away
  from friendlies (pick an "entrance"
  to your camping spot and cover it on
  your own, or use the MAC10)
- You make a ton of money as firebug --
  spread the love. No use dying rich :)

**Demolition**

- This one is tough -- leave it for
  later if you can. It's expensive and
  somewhat hard to play.
- Always stay behind friendlies -- you
  have very little "close quarter"
  killing abilities.
- It's best if your team camps in a
  spot. Stand on top of a car  or gain
  elevation in any way, and then shoot
  for clumps of small things.
- Use the M79 (single-shot) as primary,
  and leave M32 for when your team
  faces a scrake/fleshpound.

**General advice :)**

- Use a microphone, even if just for
  yelling out "scrake" or "fleshpound"
  or "need help please"
- Ask for *how much* money you need,
  not that you need money. You're way
  more likely to get money if you say
  how much you want.
- Stick to your team :)
- Look for weapons to sell -- most of
  your "advanced" weapons cost a lot of
  money, so save like a scrooge.
- Learn how to kite a lot of enemies --
  if you're screwed, cut your way out,
  and run like a .. female canine. Then,
  let them follow you, and pick 'em off
  one by one.
- Look at how other people are using a
  perk. Most of the advice above is
  from seeing what other people do and
  doing it myself. I've got most
  classes to 5 or 6, so I've picked up
  a bunch of tricks from people.

Enjoy yourself! Don't worry too much about playing on other difficulties, you'll get there eventually. Have fun with where you are.

Comment: You've covered play strategy more than how I can power-level my perks. Call me cocky but I don't think I need to learn from other people as I'm not extremely new to Killing Floor; my focus right now is getting my perks leveled because I simply cannot beat harder difficulties with the levels I have. Be sure to save your answer if anyone ever asks how to play a class though :) and I will enjoy myself.

Comment: -1 Although this is a nice answer to strategies for playing each of the perks, it does not answer the question of how to speed level the perks.

Comment: Currently MAC10 will level Firebug.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't feel like wasting time going out of your way to farm experience instead of doing the best thing for your team, you can use memory editing or [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam) to give yourself higher level perks.

With Steam Achievement Manager, choose Killing Floor from the list of games, go to the Statistics tab and check the "I understand by modifying blah-blah et cetera" box, then set the following fields to whatever you like: Damage Healder (Field Medic), Welding Points (Support), Shotgun Damage (Support), Sniper Headshot Kills (Sharpshooter), Stalkers Killed (Commando), Bullpup Damage (Commando), Melee Damage (Berserker), Flame Thrower Damage (Firebug). Values required for level 6 are listed below.

The other option is to use memory editing. My memory editor of choice is [ArtMoney](http://www.artmoney.ru/index.html) (has a free version that is perfectly sufficient for this, has no time limit and doesn't go out of its way to annoy the user), but you can use [CheatEngine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) (free) or something else entirely.

All perks can be easily earned in a **solo** game (as KF is a VAC-capable game, using memory editing while playing on a server is likely a bad idea). In this example I'm going to assume you want to level Demolition.

1. Start a match, on the perk screen note how much explosive damage you have, switch to ArtMoney and **Search** for that exact number.
2. Go back to KF and do the appropriate action to increase that number (in this example, damage something with a grenade), hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to bring up the perk menu, note the new number, switch to ArtMoney and **Filter** for the new number.
3. If you have 1 result, edit it to something like 6 million, then switch back and do the appropriate action again - instant level 6. If you got more than 1 result, repeat step 2, if you got 0 results start over from step 1.

Running KF in windowed mode will help you to quickly switch between the game and ArtMoney, you can turn windowed mode on and off by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To level Field Medic this way, you will need to download a test map that has bots that can be healed, [this one does the job](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=117243378).

The following values are needed for level 6 on different perks:

- Damage with X weapons: 5500000
- Damage healed: 100000
- Weld points: 370000
- Headshot kills: 8500
- Stalker kills: 3600

Comment: Does this work online? Meaning if i use this to level my char, will it be saved for online play?

Comment: @Lyrion yes, it most certainly will.

Comment: I successfully used https://github.com/PaulCombal/SamRewritten on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, the easiest way to level is play a Solo game on Beginner mode.  Not only do you start off with more money, but you get more money per kill.

This lets you buy the more powerful weapons more quickly, which you can use to take down the harder enemies, such as Fleshpounds.

The only problem is that waves have less mutants when you have less players.

From what I've seen, each difficulty is geared towards specific perk levels.  Beginner is geared at level 0-1, Normal at 2-3, Hard at 4, Suicidal at 5, and Hell on Earth at 6.  The only problem is that even low-level enemies even on Normal can back you into a corner in Solo mode, with no other players to back you up.

Comment: Is it worth using mutations on solo? I've tried clots only for Sharpshooter and gorefasts only for berserker, which both seemed to work well. But for Demolitions and Firebug I have no idea which mobs are the best to kill for xp grinding. I could do at best a scrakes-only if they proved good for xp; my sharpshooter is high enough level that I can down them with pistol only on the first round.

Comment: Whoops, mutations disable using perks due to Steam errors. That settles that.

Comment: @thethinman: I wasn't sure if mutations disabled perks or not.  I did notice during the Christmas event that it disabled the Christmas mutants, and I was trying to get achievements for Bad Santa. ;)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. By the way, I'm guessing you play tf2, kf, css, l4d ... do you want to exchange steam ids? I need pps to play some of these older games with.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few tips for really fast leveling without hexedit:

Play in solo-mode and use Faked Players mutator. Set Faked Players amount as 40 and start the game.

I would recommend leveling your sharpshooter first to level 6. Once you do that you can always start the map with Sharpshooter spawning with xbow (worth 600 once you'll sell it).

**SHARPSHOOTER**

You should use beginner level because you only need headshots. When you use faked players mutator (40) you should get around 600 zeds during the first wave. That's pretty ok. Just use your 9 mm and make decent headshots. Run around and find ammo (which you'll find plenty in beginner level). MountainPass is a good map for leveling Sharpshooter.

**BERSERKER**

Play in solo mode (normal) with faked players (40). Download DOOMed map and use it. In DOOMed map there's chainsaw hidden inside truck. Find it and use it against 800 zeds. Just find a narrow corridor. Once you die or complete wave 1, just restart the map again. This way you can get 1M damage / hour. So after 6 hours or so you'll have lv 6 berserker. Warning, this is boring as hell and will not make you a better zerk!

**SUPPORT**

Once you have sharshooter in lv 6 start playing support specialist. Forget solo mode and start playing with other people. Always start with sharpshooter. After first wave sell xbow and change to support perk. Buy shotgun. Use maps with narrow corridors (like biotics, offices etc.). Save money and do not buy vest. Try not to die. Play in normal mode, do not use beginner, because there are not enough zeds and you don't get decent damage from killing them. Once you have money for AA12, sell shotgun and buy AA12. Save money. Once you have more money, buy Hunting Shotgun. Once you have Hunting and AA12, buy vest.

For fast support leveling use just shotgun (shotgun, AA12, Hunting). Eventhough you run out of ammo fast. Do not save ammo. Go for every kill! Try to get as many zeds in line as possible and then take them down. Use mainly AA12, once too many zeds too close, clear them with AA12. Use both barrels for Scraces and Fleshpounds.

Practise using testmap6 (downloadable). Practise against sc and fp.

**FIREBUG**

Firebug leveling used to be very easy when weapons did not disappear between waves. You just used to buy 5 flames or so xD. Now it's a bit more difficult. In EvilSanta's Lair there is a spot where zeds can't reach you. Choose firebug and go to this place (once you'll have the firebug guns flame and mac10). This is boring as hell.

**COMMANDO**

Play with others. Try to enjoy the game. When playing other perks you can carry ak47 or pullpup to kill stalkers to help leveling commando.

**MEDIC**

Host a game and ask your friend to join. Collect money during the first wave. Change to medic and buy MP5 and MP7. At the end of wave 2 leave 1 - 2 easy zeds and let your friend take all the damage. Heal your friend with mp5 and mp7.

When playing in public servers, just heal others even if you're not playing medic. You'll notice how fast medic level will increase.

Comment: Do mutators still allow you to get xp? From what I've heard the developers have cracked down on people trying to speed level like that.

Comment: Some mutators do. For instance FakedPlayers mutator is still whitelisted. Same goes for DOOMed map. For instance Poundamonium is not whitelisted anymore.

Comment: +1 Faked Players + Mountain Pass is great for sharpshooter and zerk. Endless zombie attack is the easiest way to powerlevel medic as well. I imagine it's a lot harder to power-level other classes now that weapons disappear. Did they fix the map glitch on office? That was the easiest way to level firebug.

Comment: I can't remember the glitch on office. Where was it?

Comment: I'm quite amazed how FakedPlayers mutator is still whitelisted. It makes leveling much faster. Even if you have 800 zeds (on normal) during the first wave, you only get like 32 zeds at a time. You don't have to run after every kill, they are all for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky enough to know someone who is level 5+ of a class, jump in a game with them, go that class and ask them to throw you whatever weapon they spawn with (they should be able to buy it again as everything will be cheaper for them).

Then jump into a Hard (or Suicidal if you are game) map and start shooting. Enemies on the higher difficulties have more HP. More Hp = more dmg to kill = Faster levelling (in theory).

The other alternative is, if you want to level multiple things in the same game, is to go Beserker for the 1st wave or 2, then change to something else. At low levels, Beserker and Sharpshooter are the only classes you can level with your starting weapons. (You get grenades to level your demo.)

Comment: You can not take a weapon from one game then "jump into a Hard (or Suicidal if you are game) map and start shooting". If you leave the game you lose all your weapons.

Answer (score 0):

Demolitions is easy. The others are hard. Generally however, if you get some friends and play Poundamonium on easy you should level everything up pretty quickly. For demolitions, throw pipe bombs EVERYWHERE. Between rounds just buy up pipe bombs and leave them all over the place. This applies doubly for the last round, but leave them all in one place. A big beeping pile of pipe bombs can instakill the Patriarch pretty easily on lower difficulties.

Comment: Except Poundamonium is not whitelisted anymore (http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/List_of_whitelisted_mutators). This used to be a good trick for demo leveling but unfortunately is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Leveling Medic

Playing Objective mode on solo got this up to lvl 5 with ease.  The NPC you have to escort has constant health loss so your healing him pretty much non stop.  At the same time you'll be fighting zeds off so its good practice at being a proper combat medic.  BEWARE fleshpounders and scrakes spawn sometimes on wave 2 so buy the biggest gun you can in case.